# FOR XML AUTO, RAW SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am reading for MS 70-461 exam and when taking a look on a previous test I face the following question:

**Question:**
You need to write a Transact-SQL query that displays all the products received by a singlesupplier in the following XML format:

```
<Suppliers SupplierID="22" Company="Company Name" ContactNumber="510 250 6400">
     <Products ProductID="100" UnitPrice="249.00" UnitsInStock="7" />
     <Products ProductID="118" UnitPrice="559.00" UnitsInStock="12" />
</Suppliers>
```

**Correct Answer**

```
SELECT Suppliers.SupplierID, 
       Suppliers.CompanyName AS [Company],
       Suppliers.ContactNumber, 
       Products.ProductID, 
       Products.UnitPrice, 
       Products.UnitsInStock 
FROM Suppliers
INNER JOIN Products ON Suppliers.SupplierID = Products.SupplierID 
WHERE Suppliers.SupplierID = 22 
FOR XML AUTO, RAW
```

I try to run similar query by using FOR XML AUTO, RAW in SQL server 2012 and SQL Azure and in both cases I receive an error. Is FOR XML AUTO, RAW valid? 
How should I write the  query in order to return the above XML?

Thank you for your help

Comment: I got the same syntax error and it's just Auto. Remove the ", RAW". I'm studying for the same test. Good luck!

Comment: Here you can test your query: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/554038

Answer (score 2):

Based on MSDN [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107.aspx), RAW and AUTO are two **different** modes and can not be used together:

> In a **FOR XML** clause, you specify one of these modes:
>
> - RAW
> - AUTO
> - EXPLICIT
> - PATH
>
> The **RAW** mode generates a single  element per row in the rowset that is returned by the SELECT statement. You can generate XML hierarchy by writing nested FOR XML queries.
>
> The **AUTO** mode generates nesting in the resulting XML by using heuristics based on the way the SELECT statement is specified. You have minimal control over the shape of the XML generated. The nested FOR XML queries can be written to generate XML hierarchy beyond the XML shape that is generated by AUTO mode heuristics.

So you should use `FOR XML AUTO` in order to generate output specified in question.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!